# Java ProcessBuilder command with asterisk

Tags: java, processbuilder

This command runs from the command line successfully :

```
// /home/[user]/testproject/target/dependency/testproj-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
~/testproject/target/dependency$ jar -xf *.jar
```

But when I try to run the same command via ProcessBuilder I get :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: *.jar (No such file or directory)
```

ProcessBuilder code:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("jar", "-xf", "*.jar");
builder.directory("/home/[user]/testproject/target/dependency");
Process process = builder.start();
int exitValue = process.waitFor();
```

How can I make it work with the "*" among the command parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the command line the *shell* is performing globbing, converting `*.jar` to a list of actual files all ending with `.jar`.

When run via `ProcessBuilder` no shell is involved.  You must either:

1. Run this in a shell. I.e. the command would be `/bin/bash` or whatever shell you use and the `jar` command would be the first argument to the shell.
2. Perform the globbing yourself and specify the list of jars

Comment: No, it means the jar command is being provided with multiple jar file names on the single command line.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. (I asked before if multiple "jar" commands would be spawn by /bin/bash).